# Getting id of a selected recyclerView item android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have made a note app and everything works fine. Just in RecyclerView List when I choose an item or items and in menu I click delete button I the note is not deleted. Although delete method works in another place. 
Here's the method of delete button in menu :

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_selected) {
        for (NotePad notePad : notes) {
            if (selectedIds.contains(notePad.getId())) {
                database = new Database(this);
                database.deleteNote(notePad.getId());
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And method of delete note in my database class:

```
   void deleteNote(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
    database.close();
}
```

I don't know how to relate id of selected note to my method cause deletNote method receives long value but my selectedId is List.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

I realized my code works find but it doesn't refresh the list and also goes back from ActionMode to Toolbar. I tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: `onActionItemClicked` function is in adapter right?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun well actually I used implements ActionMode.Callback in my MainActivity.

Comment: Use can use a callback from your adapter to the activity/fragment.

Comment: So can you help me to do that? Cause everything works fine except this part.

Comment: Post your adapter here then I'll help.

Comment: sure. I'll update my post. tnx a lot.

Comment: after you delete the item, send the new note list to the adapter and call notifydatasetchanged on it, if you don't update the adapter it can't show the changes

Comment: @Cruces you are right. it deletes the note but I used adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but still nothing happened

Comment: it deletes the note but not from the internal list of the adapter, make a function in the adapter to feed it the note list instead of adding it through the adapter constructor, and after the deletion, call that method with the new list

Comment: @Cruces tnx a lot for ur answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this adapter. I have used interface.

```
public class NotePadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < NotePadAdapter.ViewHolder > {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List < NotePad > notes;
    private List < Long > selectedIds = new ArrayList < > ();
    private NoteClickListener listener;

    NotePadAdapter(Context context, NoteClickListener listener, List < NotePad > notes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.notes = notes;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface NoteClickListener {
        public void onNoteClick(NotePad notePad);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String title = notes.get(position).getTitle();
        String date = notes.get(position).getDate();
        String time = notes.get(position).getTime();

        holder.setOnClickListener() {
            listener.onNoteClick(notes.get(position))
        }

        holder.noteTitle.setText(title);
        holder.noteTitle.setText(title);
        holder.noteDate.setText(date);
        holder.noteTime.setText(time);

        long id = notes.get(position).getId();
        if (selectedIds.contains(id)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                holder.rooView.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorControlActivated)));
            }
        } else {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                holder.rooView.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent)));
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    public NotePad getItem(int position) {
        return notes.get(position);
    }

    public void setSelectedIds(List < Long > selectedIds) {
        this.selectedIds = selectedIds;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView noteTitle, noteDate, noteTime;
        ConstraintLayout rooView;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            noteTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
            noteDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_date);
            noteTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_time);
            rooView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.root_view);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ContentActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("ID", notes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In your activity/fragment where you are initiating this `adapter` pass `this` for the listener and implement the interface and whenever you click any item on the recyclerview then you will your whole NotePad object inside this function.

Comment: Sorry if it has some syntax errors. I code in Kotlin.

Comment: No problem and thanks a lot for taking your time.Just one more question. How can I now perform delete?

Comment: Umm.. delete? Do you have a delete button in your `recyclerview` item?

Comment: Yes in my actionMode menu

Comment: I don't get it. Do you have a button or not? You can pass your view with the `NotePad` in the callback then by using `findViewById` then you see which view has been clicked. And set `onClickListener` on the delete button as well as.

Comment: I found something new. My previous code works only after I rerun the app.

Comment: Then it awesome!

Comment: tnx for your help. I don't know why my data doesnt refresh.

Comment: Umm, where are you refreshing it?

Comment: I updated my code and question. In first method in onActionItemClicked after clicking on delete button

Comment: I accepted your code I didn't use it cause it had a problem that I couldn't solve but it was really nice of you.

Comment: Make sure you removed the item from the notes list in the adapter before refreshing it.

Comment: Umm? Problem? in which line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209021/discussion-between-sam-atkinson-and-ohhhthatvarun).